# Artifacts when using Serial data to trigger sketch

Tags: serial-port, processing

I am writing a small program in Processing to display the values of a speed trap and elapsed time(like a drag strip, but for a waterslide for Australia Day) coming from a microcontroller over serial.

I have had the Processing sketch running and have done most of the development with just a mouse click to imitate new data and run the program, I also have set up the hardware and had it running with the microcontroller sending the serial data and the program displaying it.

I have done some further development, and now when it runs I am getting some strange things happening, boxes sometimes come through in the wrong color, some artifacts in the displayed numbers, and a lot of wrong colors for only some of the graph(the graph is made with a for loop and the color is set outside of it).

I have tried adding in some delays to make sure its getting a full string of data and I have also tried moving around the sub routines but nothing works.

The faults only appeared after I added in the elapsed time code to the serial data, before it was just one string, now it is two numbers separated by a colon.

I have put my code in here as well, its pretty straight forward, I am only new to programming, please excuse(and point out!) any errors.

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;        
float inString;
float inFloat0, inFloat1;
float[] list = new float[0];
float[] etlist = new float[0];
PFont f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;
int index;
float rank;
float percentage;
int trapDistance = 1000;
int SgraphH = 38; //Speed graph scale
int ETgraphH = 15; //ET graph scale
int valueX = 0;
int valueY = 0;
boolean graph30 = false, graph690 = false;
color c1, c2, c3 = color(220, 0, 0), c4 = color(220, 0, 0);
int boxX = 295, boxY = 430, boxSize = 15; //Graph 30 box

void setup () {
  size(1280, 700);
  index = 0;

  //Load list from textfile
  String loadlist[] = loadStrings("list.txt");
  for (int i = 0; i < loadlist.length; i++) {
    String[] split = split(loadlist[i], ',');
    list = append(list, float(split[0]));
    etlist = append(etlist, float(split[1]));
    index++;
  }  

  println(Serial.list());
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');

  //Create fonts
  f1 = createFont("Arial Unicode MS", 20);
  f2 = createFont("Arial Unicode MS", 240);
  f3 = createFont("Arial Unicode MS", 35);
  f4 = createFont("Arial Unicode MS", 15);
  f5 = createFont("Arial Unicode MS", 15);
  f6 = createFont("Arial Unicode MS", 12);
}

void draw () {
  stroke(225);
  fill(225);
  rectMode(CORNER);
  rect(0, 0, 500, 20);
  fill(0);
  text(mouseX, 20, 20);
  text(mouseY, 50, 20);
  text(mouseX - valueX, 80, 20);
  text(mouseY - valueY, 110, 20);
}

void mousePressed() {
  //Check if Mouse is over button and toggle Graph on
  if (mouseX > boxX && mouseX < boxX+boxSize && mouseY >boxY && mouseY < boxY+boxSize) {
    if (graph30) {
      graph30 = false;
      c3 = color(220, 0, 0);
    } 
    else {
      graph30 = true;
      c3 = color(0, 220, 0);
    }
    create();
    graphCheck();
    graph();
  } 

  //Check if Mouse is over button and toggle Graph on
  if (mouseX > boxX+100 && mouseX < boxX+100+boxSize && mouseY >boxY && mouseY < boxY+boxSize) {
    if (graph690) {
      graph690 = false;
      c4 = color(220, 0, 0);
    } 
    else {
      graph690 = true;
      c4 = color(0, 220, 0);
    }
    create();
    graphCheck();
    graph();
  }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {

  delay(100);
  String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  delay(100);
  if (inString != null) {
    inString = trim(inString);
    String[] split = split(inString, ',');
    inFloat0 = float(split[0]);
    inFloat1 = float(split[1]);

    index++;
    float speed = trapDistance / inFloat0 * 3.6;
    list = append(list, speed);
    float et = inFloat1;
    etlist = append(etlist, et); 

    //Clear screen
    background(225);

    //Run sub routines
    create();
    graphCheck();
    graph();
  }
}

void delay(int delay)
{
  int time = millis();
  while(millis() - time <= delay);
}

void create() {

  //Clear screen
  background(225);  

  //Sorting
  float[] sortlist = new float[index+1];
  sortlist = sort(list);
  float[] sortetlist = new float[index+1];
  sortetlist = sort(etlist);

  //Calculate rank
  int pos = 1; 
  while (list[index-1] > sortlist[pos - 1]) {
    pos++;
  }
  if (pos == 1) {
    rank = 0;
  }
  else {
    rank = (pos / float(sortlist.length));
  }

  //Calculate Percentage of Speed
  percentage = list[index-1] / sortlist[sortlist.length -1]; 

  //Speed colour for fastest and slowest 
  if (index != 0) {
    if (list[index-1] < sortlist[1]) {
      c1 = color(240, 0, 0);
    } 
    else if (list[index-1] > sortlist[index-1]) {
      c1 = color(0, 240, 0);
    }
    else {
      c1 = color(255);
    }
  } 
  else {
    c1 = color(255);
  }  

  //ET colour for fastest and slowest 
  if (index != 0) {
    if (etlist[index-1] < sortetlist[1]) {
      c2 = color(240, 0, 0);
    } 
    else if (etlist[index-1] > sortetlist[index-1]) {
      c2 = color(0, 240, 0);
    }
    else {
      c2 = color(255);
    }
  } 
  else {
    c2 = color(255);
  }

  //Boxes
  rectMode(CORNER);
  stroke(0);
  fill(c1);
  rect(15, 15, width-30, 200); //Speed
  fill(c2);
  rect(15, 230, width-30, 200); //ET
  fill(255);
  rect(15, height - 255, 125, 240); //Left 
  rect(155, height -255, 125, 240); //Left
  rect(width - 140, height - 255, 125, 240); //Right
  rect(width - 280, height - 255, 125, 240); //Right

  //Text
  fill(0);
  textFont(f3);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("Speed", 78, height - 220);
  text("ET", width - 78, height - 220);
  text("ET", 218, height - 220);
  text("Speed", width - 218, height - 220);
  textFont(f4);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("Trap Distance: " + trapDistance + "mm", 2, height - 2);

  //Big Numbers
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textFont(f2);
  text(String.format("%.2f", list[index-1])+"km/h", width/2, 200); //Speed
  text(String.format("%.2f", etlist[index-1])+"sec", width/2, 415); //ET

  //Last 10
  for (int i = 0; i <= index-1 && i < 10; i++) {
    textAlign(LEFT);
    textFont(f5);
    text((index-1 - i + 1)+". "+String.format("%.3f", list[index-1 - i])+"km/h", 23, (height - 200 + (i * 20)));
  }

  //Last 10 ET
  for (int i = 0; i <= index-1 && i < 10; i++) {
    textAlign(LEFT);
    textFont(f5);
    text((index-1 - i + 1)+". "+String.format("%.3f", etlist[index-1 - i])+"sec", 163, (height - 200 + (i * 20)));
  }

  //Fastest 
  for (int i = 0; i <= index-1 && i < 10; i++) {
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textFont(f5);
    text((i+1)+". "+String.format("%.3f", sortlist[sortlist.length - (i+1)])+"km/h", width - 220, (height - 200 + (i * 20)));
  }

  //Fastest ET
  for (int i = 0; i <= index-1 && i < 10; i++) {
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textFont(f5);
    text((i+1)+". "+String.format("%.3f", sortetlist[i])+"sec", width - 80, (height - 200 + (i * 20)));
  }

  //Create string for saving to text file
  String[] listString = new String[index-1+1];
  for (int i = 0; i < index-1+1; i++) {
    listString[i] = (Float.toString(list[i]) + ',' + Float.toString(etlist[i]));
  }

  //Save to text file
  saveStrings("list.txt", listString);

  //Graph with curves
  //  beginShape();
  //  stroke(125, 125, 255);
  //  for (int i = 1; i <= index && i < 34; i++) {
  //    float y = map(list[index - (i - 1)], 0, SgraphH, 150, 0);      
  //    curveVertex((width + 25 - (i * 25)), 25 + y);
  //  }
  //  endShape();
}

void graph() {
  //Create graph area
  fill(255);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(width/2, height - 135, 690, 240);
  stroke(192);
  for (int i = 1; i < 30.; i++) {
    line((((width - 690)/2) + (i * (690/30))), 446, ((((width - 690)/2) + (i * (690/30)))), 684);
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    line(((width - 690)/2)+1, (445 + (i * 24)), (width - (width - 690)/2)-1, (445 + (i * 24)));
  }  

  //Graph last 690
  if (graph690) {
    stroke(0, 170, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= index-1 && i < 690; i++) {
      float start = map(list[index-1 - (i - 1)], 0, SgraphH, 240, 0);
      float end = map(list[index-1 - i], 0, SgraphH, 240, 0);
      line(((width - (width - 690)/2) + 1 - (i)), 445 + start, ((width- (width - 690)/2) + 1 - ((i + 1))), 445 + end);
    }
  }

  //Graph last 690
  if (graph690) {
    stroke(120, 0, 120);
    for (int i = 1; i <= index-1 && i < 690; i++) {
      float start = map(etlist[index-1 - (i - 1)], 0, ETgraphH, 240, 0);
      float end = map(etlist[index-1 - i], 0, ETgraphH, 240, 0);
      line(((width - (width - 690)/2) + 1 - (i)), 445 + start, ((width- (width - 690)/2) + 1 - ((i + 1))), 445 + end);
    }
  }

  //Graph last 30 speeds
  if (graph30) {
    stroke(0, 0, 240);
    for (int i = 1; i <= index-1 && i < 31; i++) {
      float start = map(list[index-1 - (i - 1)], 0, SgraphH, 240, 0);
      float end = map(list[index-1 - i], 0, SgraphH, 240, 0);
      line(((width - (width - 690)/2) + 23 - (i * 23)), 445 + start, ((width- (width - 690)/2) + 23 - ((i + 1) * 23)), 445 + end);
    }
  }

  //Graph last 30 ETs
  if (graph30) {
    stroke(240, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i <= index-1 && i < 31; i++) {
      float start = map(etlist[index-1 - (i - 1)], 0, ETgraphH, 240, 0);
      float end = map(etlist[index-1 - i], 0, ETgraphH, 240, 0);
      line(((width - (width - 690)/2) + 23 - (i * 23)), 445 + start, ((width- (width - 690)/2) + 23 - ((i + 1) * 23)), 445 + end);
    }
  }

  fill(0);
  textAlign(LEFT);
  text("0", width / 2 - 345, height - 15);
  text(SgraphH, width / 2 - 345, height - 243);
}

void graphCheck() {
  //Draw box and text for graph selection
  rectMode(CORNER);
  textFont(f6);
  textAlign(LEFT);

  stroke(0);  
  fill(0);
  text("Graph last 30", boxX+20, boxY+13);
  fill(c3);
  rect(boxX, boxY, boxSize, boxSize);

  stroke(0);  
  fill(0);
  text("Graph last 690", boxX+120, boxY+13);
  fill(c4);
  rect(boxX+100, boxY, boxSize, boxSize);
}

void keyPressed() {
  valueX = mouseX;
  valueY = mouseY;
}
```

Also, when triggered from a mouse click (turning on the graph's) it works fine.

Cheers, 
Matt

Comment: That's a lot of code-- try shaving it down to less and less functionality, but still keeping the serial-->computer communication until the problem disappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

When the subroutines were being called by the serial trigger, it some how still allowed the looped code in the draw() function to still run, which was causing the issues.

I just put noLoop() and loop() in before and after the calls for the subroutines.

All good now.